# What could cause "eth1: transmit timed out" on Debian 5.0?

Tags: debian, kernel, ethernet

I recently set up NAT using `iptables`, and I'm also doing some QoS with `tc`. While under heavy load, my server's ethernet device seemed to crash, I checked `/var/log/messages` and saw this at the time of the crash.

```
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.316993] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth1: transmit timed out
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317015] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317020] WARNING: at net/sched/sch_generic.c:222 dev_watchdog+0xa6/0xfb()
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317025] Modules linked in: cls_u32 sch_sfq sch_htb ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_conntrac
k iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables nfsd auth_rpcgss exportfs nfs lockd nfs_acl sunrpc ipv6 8021q loop psmouse parport_pc parport serio_raw fan pegasus mii 
pcspkr i2c_i801 i2c_core snd_hda_intel snd_pcm_oss snd_mixer_oss snd_pcm button rng_core iTCO_wdt snd_timer snd soundcore snd_page_alloc intel_agp evdev ext
3 jbd mbcache usb_storage sd_mod ata_piix ata_generic libata scsi_mod dock ide_pci_generic ide_core ehci_hcd r8169 uhci_hcd thermal processor thermal_sys
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317108] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.26-2-amd64 #1
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317114]
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317116] Call Trace:
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317120]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff80234a20>] warn_on_slowpath+0x51/0x7a
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317167]  [<ffffffff803cbc1e>] dev_watchdog+0x0/0xfb
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317181]  [<ffffffff8023cf6f>] lock_timer_base+0x26/0x4b
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317197]  [<ffffffff8023d0fe>] __mod_timer+0xbd/0xcc
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317224]  [<ffffffffa0032380>] :ehci_hcd:ehci_urb_dequeue+0x129/0x139
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317237]  [<ffffffff803cbc1e>] dev_watchdog+0x0/0xfb
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317248]  [<ffffffff8038f07d>] usb_hcd_unlink_urb+0x19/0x26
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317258]  [<ffffffff803cbc1e>] dev_watchdog+0x0/0xfb
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317264]  [<ffffffff803cbcc4>] dev_watchdog+0xa6/0xfb
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317270]  [<ffffffff803cbc1e>] dev_watchdog+0x0/0xfb
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317281]  [<ffffffff8023ca35>] run_timer_softirq+0x16a/0x1e2
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317298]  [<ffffffff802393fb>] __do_softirq+0x5c/0xd1
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317313]  [<ffffffff8020d2cc>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x28
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317323]  [<ffffffff8020f3d0>] do_softirq+0x3c/0x81
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317331]  [<ffffffff8023935b>] irq_exit+0x3f/0x83
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317341]  [<ffffffff8021aa6f>] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x8c/0xa4
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317350]  [<ffffffff80212c37>] mwait_idle+0x0/0x4d
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317358]  [<ffffffff8020ccf2>] apic_timer_interrupt+0x72/0x80
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317364]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff80212c78>] mwait_idle+0x41/0x4d
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317396]  [<ffffffff8020ac79>] cpu_idle+0x89/0xb3
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317431]
Nov  9 15:14:32 home-sv-1 kernel: [154733.317435] ---[ end trace b3ff89938b0e5fc2 ]---
```

So here's my opinion: eth0 is a USB ethernet adapter... Faulty drivers? How can I tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was the cheap USB Ethernet adapter I had couldn't handle the load.